# Twitter is missing from the list of Online Accounts in Ubuntu 14.04 - GNOME

Tags: gnome, 14.04, online-accounts, twitter

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with GNOME shell and from the list of "Add an Online Account", Twitter is missing. Below is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to reinstall account-plugin-twitter

```
sudo apt-get install account-plugin-twitter
```

Or you can try to install all account plugins:

```
sudo apt-get install account-plugin-*
```